# generator is instance of iterator and it is not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code. In the first validation I get `False` but `True` in second validation. Can someone help me understand how the 2 conditions are different? I am using `Python-3.9.5` on `Windows-10`

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

i1 = iter([])
g1 = (lambda : (yield))()
print (isinstance(g1, type(i1)))

print(isinstance(g1, Iterator))
```

Comment: `type(i1)` is `list_iterator`, which is a specific implementation of an iterator. `g1` is not a `list_iterator`.

Comment: ``Iterator`` is an *abstract* type of *all* iterators. ``iter([])`` is a *concrete* implementation of that type. They are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `print(type(i1))` you will see that it is not `Iterator` but `list_iterator`. That is a specific implementation of an iterator, whereas `Iterator` is the abstract base type of iterators.

Generator and list_iterator are both subtypes of the base class Iterator.

```py
>>> from collections.abc import Iterator
>>> type1 = type(iter([]))
>>> type1
<class 'list_iterator'>
>>> issubclass(type1, Iterator)
True
>>> def gen():
...   yield 1
...
>>> type2 = type(gen())
>>> type2
<class 'generator'>
>>> issubclass(type2, Iterator)
True
>>> type1 is type2
False
```